# Using bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have myPeople function, that within it calls a promise function like this

```
var myPeople = function(){
    var go;
    return new Promise (function(resolve){
        User
           .getPeople()
           .then(function(allPeople){
                go = allPeople;
                //console.log(go)
                resolve(go);
           })
        })
    return go;
}
```

if I log my go within the block i get my objects, but i can not get it to return this object..

Comment: You need to use the `then` method on the returned promise, not just on the `getPeople` method

Comment: Is there a way to get myPeople return the object itself as `{.. ..}` which i could use that way i dont have to do `myPeople().then( do something here );` ?

Comment: @goms no, there is none. This is because then there would be no way to know the method is in fact performing an asynchronous action.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of either [What is the deferred antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) or [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it is very useful one in view this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain the promise, also - avoid the `then(success, fail)` anti pattern:

```
var myPeople = function(){
    return User.getPeople()
           .then(function(allPeople){ // 
                console.log(allPeople);  
                return allPeople.doSomething(); // filter or do whatever you need in
                                                // order to get myPeople out of 
                                                // allPeople and return it

           });
        });
}
```

Then on the outside:

```
myPeople.then(function(people){
  console.log(people); // this will log myPeople, which you returned in the `then`
});
```

Comment: Ben, I get what you say,but on the outside, want to use the object returned from myPeople along with other things, that why i don't need to nest everything under myPeople.then().

Comment: @goms a promise using function performing an asynchronous action _cannot_ return a value directly. It _must_ return a promise over that value and you must unwrap it.

Comment: You might want to [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/1348195) to get the hang of asynchronisity in JS.

Comment: Thanks, most of my difficulties was that, I thought I could get the value directly somehow, I hope have well grasped the concept now. Thanks.

Comment: @goms you're welcome, feel free to use the tag (also tag your question with [promise]) if you have any more questions - it is preferred to ask them here and not in the issue tracker.

Comment: Will try to keep the issue tracker for clean/bugs. :)